# How do I make a power query refresh data from the web in less than a minute?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a power query in excel that gets Bitcoin price changes from https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/. However, the update of the prices in excel is taking an average of 7 minutes. However, the price change at the web address above is at an average of fewer than 20 seconds. This makes my power query not serve its intended purpose. How can I speed up power query in excel?

Comment: How did you make your power query refresh data from the web in more than 7 minutes?

Comment: @peter, the query itself is refreshing after seven minutes

Answer (score 0):

Put yourself in the shoes of those who are willing to help you on a voluntary basis. What exactly did you do to make the query take so long?

Maybe you are trying to read the page via web scraping (aka New web table inference)? Then I have the solution for you that will definitely be faster:

```
Get the API key from the site and request the data in csv format.
```

You are already doing that? Hope, you got the point: StackOverflow is not a guessing game ...